# User registration with e-mail + password

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to set up a user registration form allowing to register with only an e-mail and a password, in Drupal 8.

I struggled a little and decided to use the [e-mail registration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration) for Drupal.

The thing is, it only allows for an e-mail field and all other fields are removed, including the password.

How can I add a working, validated password field to a User upon registration?

Is this good practice by the way?

Comment: Are you sure that module is removing all other fields. Seeing its code it doesn't seem to remove any filed, just change the name field.

Comment: The visibility of the password field is controlled by whether e-mail verification is necessary. The password field in core is only shown when that is off, since there is strictly speaking no e-mail verification. The user simply doesn't get a password and the link is the same as a password-forgotten link.